# How to adjust a link using jQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I'm trying to do is to change the last character of a link using jQuery or Javascript.

The link that the client will input into the CMS looks something like this: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/wbc1ewhfg1jttpr/AADLfZKlfOBs5e_ueAkzffKRa/SamplePDFDownload.pdf?dl=0

What I'd like to do is to set the website to take this link and replace the '0' on the end of the link with a '1'.

Does anyone know how this could be done automatically?

Any help is appreciated,

Tom

Comment: http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/06/jquery-string-functions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As easy as that:

```
var url = document.getElementById("id of element").href;
url = url.substring(0, url.length-1);
url = url + "1";
document.getElementById("id of element").href = url;
```

Probably google first about string functions before asking...

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. Rest assured, I did try searching google for various terms before posting a question as I'm not in the business of wasting people's time. Trouble is, I wouldn't have known that 'string functions' was what I needed to search for. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

If the pattern of the url stays the same (the parameter `dl=0`) then you can simply use the [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)-function:

```
var url = 'https://www.dropbox.com/sh/wbc1ewhfg1jttpr/AADLfZKlfOBs5e_ueAkzffKRa/SamplePDFDownload.pdf?dl=0';
url = url.replace('dl=0', 'dl=1');
```